# How do I make a .bat file run when a folder is clicked

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to make some file protection software (.bat) run when I attempt to open a folder, how can this be done?

Comment: [This microsoft Administrator tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/downloads/handle#more-information) could concievably be used to monitor for a change in active handles related to a folder being accessed, However it'd be an absolutely monumental effort to devise an appropriate means to filter the output in a way that differentiates between the folder being opened by a user or being used by a process, and `Handle.exe` is not a standard part of the Windows NT installation. Batch alone would not be able to achieve your end goal, however a batch / vbs hybrid should be capable.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. That would be a huge security problem. Imagine downloading a ZIP file from the Internet, extracting it and once you open the folder, some code executes automatically. Scary! Nobody in their right mind would implement such a feature.

Also, it provides **no security whatsoever**. Your protection could be trivially bypassed by browsing the directory using command line or booting Linux from USB.

**Don't roll out custom security.** People much smarter and more experienced than me and you spent years figuring out how to do it properly. Use existing, proven solutions. Don't rely on security by obscurity. Illusion of security is worse than conscious lack of security.